# eBay API AddItemRequest PictureURLs end up as blank images

Tags: php, xml, ebay-api

I'm using the `AddItemRequest` to add pictures to an eBay item's gallery and I can't seem to get the desired result.  I got the code from a post on [GitHub](https://github.com/cahudson/eBayCommerceCookbook/tree/master/1_3_presenting_products_through_ebay) and have been referencing [eBay's AddItem API Guide here](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/AddItem.html).

```
<PictureDetails>
    <GalleryType>Plus</GalleryType>
    <PictureURL>http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTA2NlgxNjAw/z/vF0AAOSwxH1T3cQb/$_1.JPG</PictureURL>
    <PictureURL>http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTA2NlgxNjAw/z/odgAAOSwQItT3bxe/$_1.JPG</PictureURL>
</PictureDetails>
```

I've uploaded pictures to eBay's Picture Service (EPS) and used those URLs in the call, but when the item is listed there are two blank images in my gallery.  What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: @Ghost, thank you for adding the picture. Stackoverflow wouldn't allow me to do so because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: sure man no prob, you should add your current code too

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that pictures do not display in sandbox environment.

If this is not the case please paste the error message.